# Android PackageManager: check if a library APK has been installed

Tags: android, adb, android-library, android-package-managers

The `PackageManager.getPackageInfo(packageName, flags)` method can be used to check whether a specific package has been installed. It either returns the PackageInfo or throws `PackageManager.NameNotFoundException`.

How to check if a library APK is installed? An example of the library APK is Trichrome Library: https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/trichrome-library/trichrome-library-98-0-4758-101-release/trichrome-library-98-0-4758-101-3-android-apk-download/download/

After installation of this APK, calling `PackageManager.getPackageInfo('com.google.android.trichromelibrary', 0)` throws `PackageManager.NameNotFoundException`.

Looking via ADB, I see that once installed, it's not visible under `pm list packages` but it's visible under `pm list libraries` with the name "library:com.google.android.trichromelibrary".

Is there any way to determine programmatically whether the library has been installed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in the source code of `pm` in this [link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/742a67127366c376fdf188ff99ba30b27d3bf90c/cmds/pm/src/com/android/commands/pm/Pm.java#350), `pm list libraries` command uses `PackageManager.getSystemSharedLibraryNames()` which is documented [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager#getSystemSharedLibraryNames()).

If this method is not working, there are also other methods in `PackageManager` to get info about shared libraries. As mentioned by @vmayorow, One of these methods is `PackageManager.getSharedLibraries(0)`.

Comment: I have tested this method and it didn't returned the installed library name (I don't know why). But the method PackageManager.getSharedLibraries(0) returned the installed library! So I think your answer needs to be corrected to be selected.

Comment: @vmayorow `PackageManager` implementation might be device specific in some cases, and I suspect that is the reason for the method not working for you. I also updated the answer to include your solution.